# Is there a way to itereate through all frames in windbg?

Tags: windbg

Is there a way to iterate through all frames in windbg? (or to run dv for each stack frame)
For example: `~*e !mk -cc` will iterate through all threads and call `!mk -cc`

What I want is basically:

**For each thread: switch to thread:**

```
~0s
```

**For each frame in that thread:**

```
.frame 00
dv
```

Just wondering if there is a way to automate this?
Currently I am able to generate a script to do:

```
~0s
.frame 00
dv
.frame 01
dv
.frame 02
...
```

But this is a multistep process, and I want to automate it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ~e command to execute a command per-thread. Then you can use !for_each_frame to execute a command for each call frame. For example:

```
~*e .echo Thread Frames and Locals:; !for_each_frame dv
```

The .echo command is included simply to mark where one thread ends and the next begins.