# Is there a way in windbg to print the current thread id and frame id?

Tags: windbg

A bit of a follow up to: [Is there a way to itereate through all frames in windbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340917/is-there-a-way-to-itereate-through-all-frames-in-windbg)

```
~*e .echo Thread Frames and Locals:; !for_each_frame dv
```

Is there a way to echo something like:
    Current Thread#{ThreadID} Current Frame#{frame number}

I couldn't find anything about variables representing the current frame number or thread number.

The .frame command shows the current frame number.

As a simple example:  If I do:  `~*e .thread`

I get output like:

```
Implicit thread is now 000007ff`fffde000
Implicit thread is now 000007ff`fffdc000
Implicit thread is now 000007ff`fffd8000
Implicit thread is now 000007ff`fffd6000
Implicit thread is now 000007ff`ffefa000
```

But I'd like to see the windbg thread id.
Similarly, I'd like to see an example that goes through all the threads and frames and prints something like:

Current Thread#00 Current Frame#01

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that you can shut off what !for_each_frame shows you, you can only add to it. So, for example:

```
~*e .printf "Thread is: 0x%x\n", @@c++(@$teb->ClientId.UniqueThread) ; !for_each_frame .printf "Frame is: %d\n", @$frame
```

Gives you something close, but there's still some junk in the output. You'd have more flexibility if you wrote your own extension.

Comment: That is pretty close but seems to have an error with the thread portion of it.

Even if I take out the frame part - I can't get just the thread part to work:

`~*e .printf "Thread is: 0x%x\n", @@c++(@$teb->ClientId.UniqueThread)`

Gives:

`0:031> ~*e .printf "Thread is: 0x%x\n", @@c++(@$teb->ClientId.UniqueThread)
    Thread is: 0x2c9c
                                       ^ Trailing quote missing in '~*e .printf "Thread is: 0x%x
    '
                                       ^ Trailing quote missing in '~*e .printf "Thread is: 0x%x`

The first one prints fine, but the next ones don't.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting on that one.  And thanks for all of your help... I noticed you answered my last question as well :)

Comment: This may be a general windbg bug?   `~*e .printf "Thread:0x%x\n",@$tid` seemes to have the same problem.

Comment: That command works fine for me. Try updating your version of WinDbg, latest is 6.2.9200 (which, yes, is newer that 6.11)